# Unzipping Large ZIP Archives on Mac (like latest Microsoft Edge VM)

Tags: macos, zip, virtualbox, microsoft-edge, ova

After trying to unzip the latest Microsoft Edge Vm zip file on my mac I end up with a *.cpgz file.

Its supposed to result in a *.ova file for virtualBox.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: For me using a command line tool other than "unzip" worked (i.e. the built-in tar works), see the answers here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/208139/25085

Answer (score 38, accepted):

http://mattormeeple.com/2015/08/19/unzipping-large-zip-archives-on-mac-like-latest-microsoft-edge-vm/

Running the following worked great (ditto is installed by default):

```
$ ditto -x -k Microsoft\ Edge.Win10.For.Windows.VirtualBox.zip edge
```

Comment: Watch out the file name changes: `ditto -x -k {{vmDownloadName}}.zip edge`

Answer (score 4):

Tar worked for me e.g. `tar -xvf MSEdge.Win10_RS1.VirtualBox.zip`

Answer (score 0):

The way we recommended for the VMs in dev.modern.ie is to use [The Unarchiver](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?mt=12). You can know more about how to unzip them in the [instructions](http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf) (page 2).

Also the files are zip64, so any software that can handle them should be ok.

Comment: Unarchiver didn't work for me, had to use Ditto. Not sure if it's because my version is old, or the OS, but it just recursively unarchived itself.

Comment: What file did you try to unzip using Unarchiver and what is your version?

Comment: It was the Windows 8.1 IE11 ZIP file from Microsoft's own website

Comment: We haven't update that file in a long time so it is probably your Unarchiver version

Comment: Yeah could be that. I have 3.10.1 and the latest is 3.11.1