# Modern IE Windows 10 Virtualbox for Mac Zip file corrupt

Tags: macos, virtualbox, windows-10, modern.ie

I have been downloading the zip file containing the Windows 10 virtual machine for Virtualbox on Mac several times from the website below:

http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/mac/

It unzips to a .cpgz file, when you extract that file it results in a zip file and so on... This blog http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/ suggests its a corrupt zip file.

I also tried the multipart download with the same result, so I assume the VM / Zip is broken.

Did anyone use this VM with success on Mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unzipping Large ZIP Archives on Mac (like latest Microsoft Edge VM)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142947/unzipping-large-zip-archives-on-mac-like-latest-microsoft-edge-vm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Files are zip64 and you will need a tool that supports it. We recommend using "The Unarchiver" in [the instructions](http://modernievirt.blob.core.windows.net/vhd/release_notes_license_terms_1_5_15.pdf), page 2 Mac section.
The blog you point is from 2013 and the Windows 10 VMs weren't available back then.

Beware that currently there is an issue with Microsoft Edge in that specific VM: the userAgent and the headers sent by the browser are no the right ones so some websites don't work as expected. If you can download the PC version it will work OK on your Mac.

If you have any other issue with the website please let me know and I'll work on fixing it asap.

**Edit:** There is no longer any issue with the userAgent and the headers

Comment: I had the same problem. Using The Unarchiver worked, but why can't you make the zip file be one that can be unarchived using the default OSX Archive Utility? I downloaded the zip file twice to make sure it wasn't corrupt, and then had to download The Unarchiver after finding this post. Just make it so that it can be unzipped with Archive Utility. I'm also having trouble with a "'Windows10_64' is not a valid Guest OS type" error, but that's a different question...

Comment: I already tried the Unarchiver before without success (At least i thought so),   another try did the trick! Thanks Antón!

I also ran into the "Windows10_64 is not a valid Guest OS type" problem, upgrading Virtualbox to the latest version solved that problem as well.

Comment: @MattDiamant files are really big and thus the reason to use zip64. We used rar before but people complained about it. We tried different approaches and the one that worked in most OS with the software that came out of the box was this one. We'll review this again see if we find another way.

Comment: @AntónMolleda Consider pointing out right on the downloads page that they're zip64 files. Or can you make something self-extracting?